# Angular 4 datepicker 0 to 1 auto select

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am using angular 4 date picker.It works fine but when I type the date manually in yyyy-mm-dd format , the day will be auto selected for the digits of 0 to 9.

Example- if i want to enter 2019 feb 23 , when i press 2 it will automatically make the day as 02.In this case i have to backspace the day and again type 2.

I checked this with the following demo but this also has the same issue.

**DEMO:** http://kekeh.github.io/mydatepicker/

**PACKAGE** https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-datepicker

Please help me in this issue, thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to achive?

Comment: @LingVu I need to stop the 0 that automatically adds when I type the day first time.

Comment: for e.g. When I get to the day it automatically adds a zero. Its fine for a day that comes like this 2019-09-02. But if I want to add a date like 2019-09-23 the datapicker will show the result as 2019-09-023. How do I resolve this.?

Comment: I can't reconstruct your issue here: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: @LingVu Hi I'm using the datepickier in this link http://kekeh.github.io/mydatepicker/ Not the material datepicker

Comment: Then, please edit your question accordingly since you are talking about the `angular 4 date picker`. Be precise.

Comment: @LingVu I have given the proper links to the question

Comment: I also have the same issue I think the date format yyyy-mm-dd has the issue. Others I think works fine.